# how to write unit testcase for wordpress using phpunit

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, unit-testing

I am new to wordPress and  wanted to test the plugins and themes that i am using.
Steps that i have followed

- Created a wordPress server using `Flywheel`.
- Installed composer using `composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^8`
- Installed wp-cli from `curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar`
- Then tried creating test folder uisng command `$ wp scaffold plugin-tests <insert-plugin-name>` from the root directory of wordpress which is app->public
- Then i have created a database for local environment using `$ bin/install-wp-tests.sh db_name db_user 'db_password' localhost latest`

in my wp-test-config.php i have

```
<?php

// ** Database settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );

/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress database table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

I wanted to test `wp-insert` plugin that i am uisng in my site.

sample testfile `WP_Insert_Module_Test.php`  that i have is

```
  <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/modules/general/shortcode/module.php');
class WP_Insert_Module_Test  extends TestCase {

    public function testShortcode_with_valid_id() {
        // Mock shortcode attributes

        $this->assertTrue(true);
        $atts = array(
            'ninja_form_id' => '1',
            'other_attribute' => 'user_defined_value'
        );

        error_log('Value of $atts: ' . print_r($atts, true));

        // Call the function to test
       $output = wp_insert_shortcodeads_shortcode($atts);

        // Assert that the output is as expected
      //  $this->assertEquals('expected_output', $output);
    }

}
```

Previously i was using wp.config.php file directly for test environment also and when i was running the test file using command `.\vendor\bin\phpunit app\public\wp-content\plugins\wp-insert\tests` and i was getting error as below

```
Warning: require_once( path_to_site\blog-site\app\public\wp-content\plugins\wp-insert\tests\includes\modules\general\shortcode\module.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in path_of_site\blog-site\app\public\wp-content\plugins\wp-insert\tests\WP_Insert_Module_Test.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'path-of-site\blog-site\app\public\wp-content\plugins\wp-insert\tests\includes\modules\general\shortcode\module.php' 
 
Why i am gettin gabove error again and again. I am using windows11
What i tried also is

 - Tried to use seprate config file for test environment then i am getting
```

Cannot open file "path-of-site\blog-site\app\public\wp-tests-config.php".

```
Can any one tell me correct way of writing phpunit test in wordpress.


Thanks in advance.
```